# Sort array gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects:

```
[{ date: '2018 49th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1582.86, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 825 },
{ date: '2018 50th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1572.14, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 825 },
{
  date: '2018 51st',
  '3_SLS93 N/P': 1582.86,
  '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 828.57,
},
{
  date: '2018 52nd',
  '3_SLS93 N/P': 1562.14,
  '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 835.71,
},
{ date: '2019 1st', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1555, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 833.33 },
{ date: '2017 48th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1560.0, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 1255 }];
```

I want to sort ascending base on `date` value, so the result will like this:

```
[{ date: '2017 48th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1560.0, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 1255 }, { date: '2018 49th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1582.86, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 825 },
    { date: '2018 50th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1572.14, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 825 },
    {
      date: '2018 51st',
      '3_SLS93 N/P': 1582.86,
      '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 828.57,
    },
    {
      date: '2018 52nd',
      '3_SLS93 N/P': 1562.14,
      '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 835.71,
    },
    { date: '2019 1st', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1555, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 833.33 }];
```

I use `sort()` only, but it doesn't change.

Comment: sort based on which value?

Comment: sort by what? And what does that date refer to? 2018 48th?

Comment: @MonicaAcha date value.

Comment: Not a valid date format

Comment: Well, javascript isn't some sort of magical tool that reads in your mind. You need to specify on what property you want to sort and how to parse the value in order to understand what's bigger than the other.  Your date format isn't in any standard format, so you need to specify how to read it

Comment: @CristianTraìna as the document of `sort` function, it says that if I omitted parameters then it will sort ascending based on characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom sort function, like this:

```js
var array = [{ date: '2018 49th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1582.86, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 825 },
{ date: '2018 50th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1572.14, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 825 },
{
  date: '2018 51st',
  '3_SLS93 N/P': 1582.86,
  '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 828.57,
},
{
  date: '2018 52nd',
  '3_SLS93 N/P': 1562.14,
  '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 835.71,
},
{ date: '2019 1st', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1555, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 833.33 },
{ date: '2017 48th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1560.0, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 1255 }];

sorted_array = array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.date < b.date) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.date > b.date) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(sorted_array);
```

Here is also a shorter version if you prefer short code:

```js
var array = [{ date: '2018 49th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1582.86, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 825 },
{ date: '2018 50th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1572.14, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 825 },
{
  date: '2018 51st',
  '3_SLS93 N/P': 1582.86,
  '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 828.57,
},
{
  date: '2018 52nd',
  '3_SLS93 N/P': 1562.14,
  '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 835.71,
},
{ date: '2019 1st', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1555, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 833.33 },
{ date: '2017 48th', '3_SLS93 N/P': 1560.0, '320_Oleic Acid 75 min': 1255 }];

sorted_array = array.sort((a, b) => (a.date > b.date) - (a.date < b.date));

console.log(sorted_array);
```